# check when a button is clicked event qt

Tags: c++, qt

I am a beginner in Qt and I would like to know, how can I create an event which checks when a button in the windows gets clicked? The window has a single push button.

I could not find a simple and correct example for my question, that's why I am asking here. I did google first.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

```
class MyClass : public QWidget
{
public:
  MyClass ()
  {
    QPushButton *pButton = new QPushButton(this);
    QObject::connect(pButton, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &MyClass::onButtonClicked);
  }

public slots:
  void onButtonClicked () {qDebug () << "Button clicked";};
};
```

`onButtonClicked` will be called if the button pressed.

Please see [signals & slots](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html) and [QPushButton signals](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qabstractbutton.html#signals) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Qt employs the signals and slots paradigm. You don't check if a button is clicked. When a button is clicked, it emits a signal. You can connect your own functions to that signal. So whenever that button is clicked, the signal is emitted, and triggers all the functions it is connected to.

Be sure to check out [signals and slots](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.8/signalsandslots.html), which is a core concept of Qt, along with properties and meta data.

Note that as a `QWidget` derived, a button comes with the following methods, which are triggered by mouse events and you can override them if you wish, although in the case of something as a button that is hardly necessary:

```
virtual void    mouseDoubleClickEvent(QMouseEvent * event)
virtual void    mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent * event)
virtual void    mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent * event)
virtual void    mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent * event)
```